# Disabling Bloom gesture on Hololens device

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-10-universal, hololens

I am developing on Hololens. My question is simple : **is there any way you can disable the bloom gesture (gesture that pause the application and you to "home")**. It is annoying when you need to perform physical movement in front of you that aren't linked to your application.

I read there https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/gestures that this gesture is handled by the OS and cannot be handled inside my app.

Thanks

Comment: Does it take you to the home screen without you doing this: "To do the bloom gesture, hold out your hand, palm up, with your fingertips together. Then open your hand."? If yes, please file a bug using the feedback hub app.

Comment: No it doesn't, and it's not a bug. The thing is, it's too easy to do that gesture "accidentally". Maybe it's too sensible. It seems like I have no control at all on that gesture and that is what's annoying me :(

Comment: I would still suggest to raise this as a feed back. The threshold might need some tweaking!

Comment: Agreed, I'll start with that! But I'd only use voice command to quit my app if it was possible..

Comment: I believe that there are certain apps that block the bloom gesture in the developer version (Learn gestures, and Holographic remoting are examples of that). Thus, there has to be a system API that handles this gesture before it reaches the operating system default handler.

Comment: Moreover, I also experienced problems with some users triggering this gesture accidentally. It is a bit annoying when it happens mid a user study.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, but I couldn't find that system API anywhere. If you ever find anything, make sure to leave a solution here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the commercial version of the HoloLens you can have a app run in Kiosk mode. then only that app will be available and the blook gesture won't work

Answer (score 1):

it's definitely a bit late for the answer but I hope it can help others. It is possible to inhibit the gesture by placing a strip of adhesive tape on the visor as in the picture I attach.

[A little trick to disable gesture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5hol.jpg)